# Can we generate SQL Server MDS Model from an existing database schema?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, master-data-services

I have googled this quite a bit and am surprised to not find an answer.

I'm considering using SQL Server MDS to manage our canonical schema, but I certainly don't want to key in my entire database schema to create the Model.

- Does SQL Server MDS support creating a Model by reverse engineering a database?

Answer (score 0):

> Does SQL Server MDS support creating a Model by reverse engineering a database?

I wrote a command-line utility to do this, called [MdsModelImport](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mdsutilities).  It's intended to be a one-time import, and simply save you from having to type all the attributes.

Comment: I get this error when I try your link   The site ahead contains harmful programs
Attackers on archive.codeplex.com might attempt to trick you into installing programs that harm your browsing experience (for example, by changing your homepage or showing extra ads on sites you visit). Learn more

Comment: Not sure what's flagging the site, but Codeplex was an open code sharing site (like github), so there's all sorts of different stuff there.

Comment: ok :)   So is your answer "No", then?

Comment: If the question is whether that project contains any malicious code, then no.  It's Microsoft sample code written by me, working with customers implementing MDS :)